# Tell pianist to play entire piece softly, except one part

Tags: piano, notation, dynamics

I've composed a short melody, however I'm very new to all this piano theory, how would I tell the pianist to play the entire piece softly? (*mp*, not *pp*), and how would I write exceptions for specific notes? For example, take this piece of music.[image]

How would I get the pianist to play the entire piece softly, but the bar in red, to be played regularly?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The conventional method is to write ***sempre mp*** in the first measure. *Sempre* means *always*.

The exceptional measure could be marked as ***più forte*** ("louder"), followed by ***sempre mp*** again.

Another possibility is ***rinforzando*** ("reinforced") with a dashed line after it to indicate the emphasized part. Individual notes can be marked as ***rfz***.

Answer (score 54):

Another approach would be to simply state the instructions either in a blob of text preceding the music page or perhaps somewhere between the title and the music:

[image: vuvuzela concerto in D]

This though would require translation should the work be published for e.g. Klingons or Lojbanists who may be familiar with classical music scoring conventions but not English.

```
% LilyPond engraving system - http://www.lilypond.org/
\version "2.18.0"
\header {
  title = "Vuvuzela Concerto in D"
}

\markup {
  \vspace #2
  \italic {
    "Play entire piece softly ("
    \dynamic mp
    ") except for measure 7." }
}

bbbb = {
 \tempo 4=96
 bes1~bes~bes~bes~bes~bes~bes\ppp
}

\score {
  \new Staff << \bbbb >>
  \layout { }
}
```

(Redundant information may also help future translators link language to the musical notation of the time, and will otherwise help reinforce the composer's intentions—however bizarre they may seem.)

Comment: Yeah, that is pretty hilarious. It's got to be one of the more difficult pieces in the vuvuzela repertoire.

Comment: Can a vuvuzela be played *ppp*? Would circular breathing help that long note? So many questions...

Comment: Vuvuzela Concerto in D. Key signature is C. The entire song is a Bb played for seven measures. This checks out.

Comment: I come from South Africa, the not-so-proud home of the Vuvuzela. Up until this day, I did not know that there was such a thing as a "Vuvuzela Concerto"

Comment: @Kevin: Like most wind instruments, the vuvuzela is a transposing instrument. This concerto is scored for a vuvuzela in E. (Since the vuvuzela repertoire is mostly atonal, key signatures are typically not employed).

Comment: @Restioson https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wf2P8SnOwLo

Answer (score 51):

Why are we making such a fuss over this?  If you want the piece to start mp, write 'mp' in the first bar.  If you want a particular section played mf, write 'mf' at that point. Then 'mp' again.
A confirmatory '(sempre mp)' might be useful at a new section of the piece.

BTW, there is no such thing as 'regular volume'.   If you want mf, say so.

Comment: If the piece is longer than a few bars, then some pianists may interpret ***mp*** as merely a starting point, rather than as something that needs to be maintained throughout. I think that it is worth adding ***sempre*** if an even volume is important.

Comment: @AndrewWoods I'm not so sure; if there were no other markings then I'd say you're right.  If there is a bar in the middle with a different marking and then back to mp in the subsequent bar, there is no ambiguity whatsoever.  If you want to enforce dynamics in the player beyond what is conventional, I would like to point out that the player is free to ignore your markings anyway.

Comment: Blimey!  My concise, common-sense answers aren't always THAT popular!  :-)

Answer (score 14):

You can instruct the pianist to use the [soft pedal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_pedal#Musical_notation) by writing *una corda* above the score, at the very beginning.

Mark the louder passage with *tutte le corde* or *tre corde* to indicate normal volume.

Soft pedal can affect timbre. If you don't want that, you can just use the [standard dynamic markings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamics_(music)#Dynamic_markings) to indicate soft (piano) or loud (forte) in the appropriate sections.